# How to add two components in one single Vue file to export?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, ag-grid, vuetify.js

I am trying to make a component of two buttons in a single file to export it into a single column into ag-grid-vue. I am able to display only one button per column. Here's my code:

```
  <template>
  <div>
      <v-btn fab small style="height: 24px; width:24px; margin-top: -1.5px;"
          color='primary'
          block='true'
          @click.stop="dialogEdit = !dialogEdit">
          <v-icon>fa-pencil</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
      <v-btn fab small style="height: 24px; width:24px; margin-top: -1.5px;"
        color='primary'
        block='true'
        @click.stop="dialogDelete = !dialogDelete">
        <v-icon>fa-trash</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
  </div>
  </template>
  <script>
  import Vue from 'vue';
  export default Vue.extend({
    methods: {
      invokeParentMethod () {
        this.params.context.componentParent.methodFromParent(
          `Row: ${this.params.node.rowIndex}, Col: ${
            this.params.colDef.headerName
          }`
       );
     }
    } 
  });
  </script>
```

I am importing this file in my web page design to add component and then use it in the grid's column to edit and update records in the grid. Neither its showing the error nor the button I changed the style and margins too but no sign of the delete button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it the code above is working properly just need to remove block='true' from both button components. This property expands the button to 100% of available space so other button was getting overlapped.